# Display issue in Laravel 5.5 registration form's errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I created a registration form using make:auth command in Laravel 5.5. Its working alright but not showing errors when validation fails. I've checked many times that code to display errors exists in template but still getting this error.

Template Location:

```
resources/views/mybladetemplate
```

Method in Controller:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'field1' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'emailField' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'fieldPwd' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'anotherfield' => 'string'
    ]);
}
```

RegistersUsers Trait:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Registeration Form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('field1') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Field Name</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="field1" type="text" class="form-control" name="field" value="{{ old('field1') }}" required autofocus>
                            @if ($errors->has('field1'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('field1') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('emailField') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="emailField" type="email" class="form-control" name="emailField" value="{{ old('emailField') }}" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('emailField'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('emailField') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="anotherfield" class="col-md-4 control-label">Another Field</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="anotherfield" type="text" class="form-control" name="anotherfield" value="{{ old('anotherfield') }}" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('fieldPwd') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="fieldPwd" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="fieldPwd" type="password" class="form-control" name="fieldPwd" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('fieldPwd'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('fieldPwd') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Register
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Are there no errors showing for any of the fields or are only some errors missing?

Comment: `<?php print_r($errors); ?>` At the top of your from and share output ?

Comment: @C2486 this is output after print_r Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag Object ( [bags:protected] => Array ( ) )

Comment: @DelenaMalan It is not showing any error

Comment: it should display error if validation fails

Comment: @C2486. I wonder why it is not displaying any error :(. The user come back to the registration page but displays no error and it also does not populate form.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple code in your blade to show all of the errors in a ul li structure :

```
        @if($errors->any())
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <div class="alert alert-warning" dir="rtl">
                    <ul>
                        <li>{!! $error !!}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        @endif
```